# Copy windows path into linux based terminals: Conemu, Cygwin, Git Bash

Tags: windows, path, cygwin, git-bash, conemu

When I copy a windows path from windows explorer's location bar, `C:\Users\Administrator\Links`, it gets automatically translated to one of the following:

Cygwin in Conemu:
`/mnt/c/Users/Administrator/Links`

Git bash in Conemu:
`/mnt/c/Users/Administrator/Links`

Cygwin64 Terminal:
(no translation)
`C:\Users\Administrator\Links`

Git Bash on Windows:
(no translation)
`C:\Users\Administrator\Links`

But Cygwin actually wants `C:/Users/Administrator/nextcloud/diary`
or
`/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/nextcloud/diary`

and Git Bash actually wants `/c/Users/Administrator/Links`

So each time I try to `cd` into that directory, I get `bash: cd: /mnt/c/Users/Administrator/Links: No such file or directory`. Then I have to manually change the path.

Is there a way to change Conemu's "translation" rule? Do you experience the same problems when using linux terminals with/without Conemu? How did you cope with this?

Edit:

The `Git Bash` is started in Conemu by setting up a task with commands:
`C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe --no-cd --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -new_console:t:"Git Bash"`
and `Cygwin` is started in Conemu with commands `D:\app\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat -new_console:t:"cygwin"`

Comment: You should describe how do you start your ConEmu tabs. Exact commands.

Comment: Cygwin and msys/mingw64 have a bashhere

Comment: Ignore my previous comments. See the Cygwin chere package. It sets up an explorer context option that opens a Cygwin terminal on the selected directory. It can also open other apps with other terminals and shells. Also the win10 windows terminal adds its own option there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @cisco.prog 's answer

In Startup > Tasks

I added `-cur_console:m:"/cygdrive"` for Cygwin and `-cur_console:m:"` for Git Bash.

Then I **restarted** Conemu to make changes take effect.

Now when I paste windows path into Cygwin tab, it is automatically converted to `/cygdrive/c/path/to/file`. When I paste windows path into Git Bash tab, it is automatically converted to `/c/path/to/file`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem using Cmder (which uses Conemu).
In the launch options (in Cmder, it's in Startup - Tasks), you must select the task (for example bash :: bash) and add:

`-cur_console: m: ""`.

Indeed, according to the documentation:

https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax

in the options of -cur_console, we can read:

> m: / mnt - defines ‘/ mnt’ prefix for Unix-path conversion, m: "" - no
> prefix

Comment: Thanks for the hint. For me that didn't work because of the spaces. 
After removing the spaces it worked.
Example: `code` -cur_console:m:"" `code`